# IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

Tags: matplotlib, cluster

Estoy realizando un cluster K means, al graficar el siguinte cdig me sale error:

`código`

```
fig= plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_xlabel('Componente 1 ',fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Componente 2 ',fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Componentes principales',fontsize=20)
color_theme=np.array(['blue','green','orange',])
ax.scatter(x=pca_nombres_data.Componente_1, y=pca_nombres_data.Compononte_2,
          c=color_theme[pca_nombres_data.KMeans_Clusters],s=50)
plt.show()
```

`código`

el error por lo que evidencio es en la siguiente linea

`código`

```
ax.scatter(x=pca_nombres_data.Componente_1, y=pca_nombres_data.Compononte_2,
          c=color_theme[pca_nombres_data.KMeans_Clusters],s=50)
```

`código`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo. pues al parecer en mi humilde opinion estas llamando una referencia nula de un vector creo que puede ser color_theme[pca_nombres_data.KMeans_Clusters], deberias correrlo en frio y ver en inspeccion rapida, el tamaño del vector color_theme que sea mayor o igual que el valor que tiene pca_nombres_data.KMeans_Clusters . chequealo y cuenta que te da.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, al reemplazar la linea que mencionas ahora sale este error     SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: amigo creo que no entendiste, no te dije que reemplazaras ninguna linea, fue que lo ejecutes linea por linea y cuando llegues a ese codigo te dara el error, en ese momento sabras cual es la linea, si efectivamente es esa linea, entonces verifica que el tamaño del vector color_theme[] sea mayor que el indice que estas  enviando pca_nombres_data.KMeans_Clusters

Comment: muchas gracias, efectivamente el error era que la matriz de colores era menor al requerido.

Comment: a bueno me contenta. recuerda poner en la flechita hacia arriba que si te ayudo mi comentario.